# How Can I specify server to use for mail command

Tags: linux, email, command-line-interface

I am working on a crontab job that runs a script, which looks in a specific directory for the existence of a file. If the file does not exist it exits. However, if the file exists it sends an E-mail using the mail command.

But since this is more of a secure system the E-mail servers are not configured so I only have the mail command line and cannot install other software on the system. How can I specify which server to use from the mail command line.

Comment: What "command" in particular? What distro are you using? Is this a bash script?

Answer (score 4):

I was going to say "you can't", but apparently you can.  `mailx`, which is what's installed as the `mail` command on most modern UNICES, says in the man page that you can set a variable:

> Normally,  mailx  invokes  sendmail(8) directly to transfer messages. 
>   If the smtp variable is set, a SMTP connection to the server specified
>   by the value of this variable is used instead.  If the SMTP server
>   does not use the standard port, a value of server:port can be given,
>   with port as a name or as a number.

Check the `man` page for your mail command on how to set this.